# JavaFX - Get MouseEvent position with scale

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have a problem with JavaFX. I want get the correct position of a scaled area with MouseEvent. It works with the default scale (1.0), but if I scale down or up the values are wrong.

```
area.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
   @Override
   public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
      System.out.println(event.getSceneX());
   }
});
```

Comment: When using scene coordinates? I cannot reproduce the issue. When I test this event handler it properly prints the distance of the mouse from the left border of the window in pixels. You don't retrieve the position of an *area* though. Could you add a [mcve] to the question and describe the expected behaviour?

Comment: I think I misunderstand event.getSceneX(). I thought it represents the relative mouse position of the area and not of the window.

Comment: If you want the position relative to the node where the event handler is added, you need to use the `x`/`y` properties of `MouseEvent`. These coordinates are the values in the coordinate system of this node before any transformation is applied to them.

Comment: @fabian Thank you. Now I use getX()/getY() and it's work. Silly that I didn't look in the docs.